# Is it better to show all options or let user add options in a form

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, user-centered-design, ux-designer

So I'm designing a tool for system administrators and one thing I am having trouble with is the large amount of info that is required for certain tasks. There is a section where the user has 4 different optional options to choose from and I'm not sure whether its best to let the user add them if needed or to just show them all in once form. I have created two wireframes to show my two options.

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind that the rest of this form is extremely long as well, so it would be beneficial if I could shorten the length, but I am not sure if this is the best approach to do it

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to mind was this:

[image]

Hide the advanced options, but show the user clearly where he could find them if needed. Those users that do click on that button are expecting to see many forms, so it's okay to show as in your first example (vertical stack of forms is better readable).

Comment: Do you think there are any downsides to hiding the 4 options? Im worried that users won't know the options exist if they're in a hidden menu, but I can see how that may not be an issue for things that are optional

Comment: @GeneLee That is hard to say without knowing your users specifically. I think you (or someone else who knows) can decide that based on your knowledge of the user's needs. On the other hand, if they are indeed important enough, maybe it is worth it to display everything openly then, with the drawback that it becomes very long. There is no easy yes or no answer here :)